# How do I add a function to parent theme

Tags: php, functions, hooks

I am looking for advice on how to add a function / hook to a parent theme.

A colleague has installed a WordPress theme, but not child theme   as I have tried adding a function to the child theme but it didn't work.
So I am looking for advice on how to add extra functions to the parent theme.
Kind regards

Comment: whaat do you mean by tried adding func to child theme but it didn't work

Comment: A client has installed a WordPress parent theme and has asked me if I can add a hook to a parent theme,  I have tried to add it to the functions.php page, but it didn't work.

Comment: So I wasn't sure if this was possible?

Comment: what is the hook supposed to do?

Comment: and how did you try to add it? share that code by editing the post

Comment: I want to change 'out of stock ' to 'sold' I have the code but I am only able to do it via a plugin.

Comment: you have to share the code that you added, how you added it, where you added it, etc. so tht someone can guide you.

Comment: I went into Appearance and then theme editor, went into functions.php and added the code

Comment: Thanks for your help 

Comment: There's no reason an arbitrary function would work in a parent theme but not a child theme. If you have code that's not working you need to share that code and the problem you're trying to solve. The question "how do I add a function to parent theme" doesn't really make sense on its own.

Comment: Many thanks for that reply. I have resorted to using a plugin to achieve my goal.